Checkbox cell value, multiple IF formulae
I'm trying to correlate a checkbox with a number value as per below i.e. if D4 is TRUE then value shown in G4 = 3
So far I can get G4 =if(D4,3,0) to produce this but cannot apply the rule to the whole row
Is this a case of writing multiple IF formulae to one cell or something else?
enter image description here

In G4 enter a formula:
=MATCH(TRUE,$B4:$F4,0)

Copy down as required. The first match in each row will be shown.

You could use array formula also. For example, with checkboxes in D4:D11, enter in G4 (no need to fill down):
Since TRUE = 1 and FALSE = 0,
=D4:D11*3



=LET(a,B2:F5,c,COLUMNS(a),b,MMULT(SEQUENCE(,c)*a,SEQUENCE(c,,,0)),IF(b,b,""))
This will spill the result per row, where a is the range containing the check boxes.
Or the same:
=LET(a,B2:F5,b,BYROW({1,2,3,4,5}*a,SUM),IF(b,b,""))
